# Can't run swift app that I've got from GitHub?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, alamofire

I've been reading this book "Learn Swift by Building Applications: Explore Swift Programming Through IOS" to learn swift.
they have an app in chapter 9 which is a complete weather app.
I went to their [GitHub](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Learn-Swift-by-Building-Applications) and downloaded the app but when i want to run in in my mac,it shows build failed.
how can i fix that and run the app?
i want to see the app running before building it myself.
I'm using xcode 10.

Update: I've installed cocoapods and figured out a way to install alamofire.now the only error left is Toast_Swift. i have to figure out a way to insatll this one as well.any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As Piotr mention below, you need to use Cocoapods.
Try this tutorial to learn how to use cocoapods: https://www.raywenderlich.com/626-cocoapods-tutorial-for-swift-getting-started

Comment: Could you please post the full error message? That will help us to understand the issues more clearly.

Comment: There are so many errors and that is getting out of control.Actually the book is very new,so i think there should be some errata in the codebase of the book. i will leave a review of the book for sure,because this is very confusing for a person who just try to learn a language and had to deal with all those errors.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use cocoapods https://cocoapods.org/

- Install cocoapods
- Run pod install
- And open WeatherApp.xcworkspace